# TextBox onBlur Value from jQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am adding DatePicker to a class of fields.  The calendar control displays nicely and a value shows in my textbox when I select a date.

When I click off the field, the textbox onblur does not see the value.  Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();                
});
</script>


<input type="text" id="A4" name="A4" size="10" class="datepicker" value="" style="text-             align: right; background-color: #FFFFFF;" title="A4" tabindex="34"
onclick="return clickValue(this,'A4');"  
ondblclick="dblClickValue(this,'A4')"  
onfocus="focusValue(this,'A4')"  
onblur="return blurValue(this,'A4')"  
onkeypress="return keyPressHandle(this,event,'A4')" 
onkeyup="return keyUpHandle(this,'A4')" 
onkeydown="return keyDownHandle(this,event,'A4')">

function blurValue(obj,field) {
    alert(obj.value + field);
if(gAutoFormulate && gField==field) return true;

//restoreCellColor( obj );
saveAndSetValue(obj,field);

return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of that `blurValue(this,'A4')"` method?

Comment: I think the problem is the textbox blur occurs before the datepicker puts a value in the textbox.  Not sure how to get around this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the text box blur event will occur before datepicker will put in its value.  I invoked the blur from datepicker's close event.

```
$(function() {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
       onClose: function() {        
       $(this).trigger('blur');
       }
   });
}); //ready
```